# Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence for a non-normal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences, lie-algebra-cohomology

1. Is there an analogue of the Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence for a non-normal subgroup?
2. What can you say about it? Can you describe $E^{p, q}_1$ ? What is about $E^{p, q}_2$?
3. What is the best technique to get the spectral sequence? For me the Grothendieck spectral sequence us much better than the spectral sequence of a filtered complex.

There is a parallel question which is likely easier.

1. Is there an analogue of the Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence for a Lie subalgebra which is not an ideal?

2 and 3 remain the same.

I already asked [a version of this question on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112179/) but got no responses.

Comment: The main difficulty is that, if $H < G$, there is not really a functor that will take the $H$-fixed points and produce the $G$-fixed points unless you include extra data. There are methods to get the cohomology of $G$, but almost all of them will require as extra input the cohomology of intersections of conjugates of $H$.

Comment: It is very interesting. Can you provide references?

Comment: The shortest way to say it is the following. For a group $G$, the category of $G$-modules is equivalent to the category of quasicoherent (etale) sheaves on the classifying stack $BG$, and the global section functor is the fixed-point functor. There is a faithfully flat cover $BH \to BG$, and so there is a Cech-to-derived / descent spectral sequence. But to compute effectively with it, you need to know the iterated fiber products of $BH$ over $BG$, which correspond to $G$-orbits in $(G/H)^k$.

Comment: From the point of view of filtered complexes, this is a little easier to do because there is a nonprojective resolution of $\Bbb Z$ by a complex with terms $\Bbb Z[(G/H)^k]$, with the same boundary operator as on homogeneous chains. You can apply $\Bbb RHom_G(-,M)$ to this resolution and get a filtered complex, and this gives you the spectral sequence too.

Comment: (In answer to your explicit question, no, I do not know an immediate reference for this. I do know that this technique, from the topological point of view, appears in calculations of homological stability (I think it's used in Quillen's calculations for number fields). The chain complex I just described is the simplicial chain complex of a "classifying space for the family of subgroups of $H$".)

Comment: @Tyler Lawson , I do not belive in complex $ \mathbb{Z} [  (G/H)^k ] $ . You have to have group structure on $G/H$ to explain what is "the same boundary operator".

Comment: @Tyler: in more topological language, is this equivalent to taking the Serre spectral sequence associated to the fiber sequence $F \to BH \to BG$, where $F$ is the homotopy fiber of the natural map $BH \to BG$?

Comment: @quinque You are thinking of the boundary operator on inhomogeneous chains, e.g. $d g_0(g_1,g_2) = g_0 g_1(g_2) - g_0(g_1g_2) + g_0(g_1)$. I am talking about the boundary operator on homogeneous chains: $d[g_0,\ldots,g_n] = \sum (-1)^i [g_0,\ldots,\widehat{g_i},\ldots,g_n]$, where $G$ acts diagonally.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't think so. In that case, the fiber is the discrete set $G/H$ and so the Serre spectral sequence degenerates. I believe that it may be the Leray spectral sequence associated to the map $(E{\cal F} \times EG)/G \to E{\cal F}/G$ where $E{\cal F}$ is a certain contractible $G$-space (the classifying space for families that I mentioned earlier).

Comment: This works when analyzing $(X \times EG)/G \to X/G$ for any contractible $X$. For example, when you have a group $G$ that acts on a tree $T$ sufficiently nicely, you get a method for computing the cohomology of $G$ in terms of some kind of sheaf cohomology of $G/T$ where the stalks are the cohomology of the stabilizers.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for reviving an old question, but it seems that the *Kropholler spectral sequence* exactly answers the first 3 questions:

*Kropholler, P.H.*, [**A generalization of the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence with applications to group cohomology and decompositions of groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/JGT.2006.001), J. Group Theory 9, No. 1, 1-25 (2006). [ZBL1115.20042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1115.20042).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. The LHS spectral sequence can be thought of as the Serre spectral sequence associated to the fiber sequence

$$BN \to BG \to B(G/N)$$

where $G$ is a group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of it. If $N$ is not required to be normal then the third term in this fiber sequence no longer exists, so it's unclear to me in what sense we can have a reasonable analogue of the LHS spectral sequence here.

Comment: What you said is just that this approach does not work. But I mean something different. I even edited my question, wrote "analog of Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence".

Comment: http://www.math.ru.nl/~solleveld/scrip.pdf
Here you can find a definition of relative Lie algebra cohomology. It is done by means of explicit complex but it is still a way to make sense of such kind of objects.

Comment: @quinque: that notion of relative Lie algebra cohomology is a little different. If you think of the cohomology of Lie algebras as an algebraic model of the de Rham cohomology of compact Lie groups $G$, then relative Lie algebra cohomology should be an algebraic model of the de Rham cohomology of homogeneous spaces $G/H$. Of course these can make sense if $H$ is not normal, but for *group* cohomology we want to compute the cohomology of the *delooping* of these spaces, and we just can't deloop homogeneous spaces in general.

Comment: Yes, relative cohomology are cohomology of homogenious space! And moreover there is a spectral sequence of a bundle. But I want to get this sequence for arbitrary Lie algebra. Here have to be purely algebraic approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

For Lie algebras $\mathfrak h \subseteq \mathfrak g$ and a $\mathfrak g$-module $M$ there is a spectral sequence arising from the following filtration $F_i C^q(\mathfrak g, M)$ on the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $C^q(\mathfrak g,M)$. The filtration is defined by

$$ F_iC^q(\mathfrak g, M) = \{ \gamma \mid i_{h_1}i_{h_2}\cdots i_{h_{q+1-i}}\gamma = 0 \text{ for all }h_i \in \mathfrak h\},$$
where $i_{h}$ means contraction by $h$ (putting $h$ into one argument).

The $E_1$-page may be identified as
$$ E_1^{j,i} = H^i(\mathfrak h, Hom(\wedge^j \mathfrak g/\mathfrak h, M)).$$
When $\mathfrak h$ is an ideal, all of this coincides with the Grothendieck spectral sequence for the composition of $(-)^{\mathfrak h}$ and $(-)^{\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h}$.

---

Reference: Hochschild, G., & Serre, J. P. (1953). Cohomology of Lie algebras. *Annals of Mathematics*, 591-603.